# I'm struggling with adding php count to login attempts on my login?

Tags: php

```
// Admin Login Function
function Admin_Login() {
    $results = array();
    $results['pageTitle'] = "Admin Login - Admin";
    $results['pageHeading'] = "Admin Login";
    $results['pageHeading_p'] = "Login must be provided in order to gain administrative access.";
    $results['foo'] = "foo";
    if (isset($_POST['Admin_Login'])) {
                 // User Has Posted The Login Form: Attempt To Log The User In
        if ($_POST['username'] == ADMIN_USERNAME && $_POST['password'] == ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
                  // Admin Logged In - Create Session
            $_SESSION['username'] = ADMIN_USERNAME;
                  // UseT Bad Sessions & Resume To Admin
            if (isset($_SESSION['suspect_user'])) { unset($_SESSION['suspect_user']);unset($_SESSION['login_count']);}header("Location: Admin.php");
            } elseif ($_POST['username'] != ADMIN_USERNAME && $_POST['password'] != ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
                // User Triggered Session Bad User
            $_SESSION['suspect_user'] = 'Suspect User Bad';
            $results['errorMessage'] = "Incorrect username & password. Please attempt again using the correct username & password.";
            require(ROOT.Admin_INCLUDES."/Forms/Admin_Login.php");
            } elseif ($_POST['username'] != ADMIN_USERNAME || $_POST['password'] != ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
                // User Triggered Session Possible User 
            $_SESSION['suspect_user'] = 'Suspect User Good';
            $results['errorMessage'] = "Incorrect username/password. Please attempt login again.";
            require(ROOT.Admin_INCLUDES."/Forms/Admin_Login.php");
            } if ($_SESSION['login_count'] >= 3 && $_SESSION['suspect_user'] == 'Suspect User Bad') {
               // Login failed Under Session Bad User - Block The User
            $HTAccess_file = fopen(ROOT."/.htaccess", "a+");
            $htaccess_log =PHP_EOL."<Files Admin.php>".PHP_EOL."Order Allow,Deny".PHP_EOL."Deny from ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].PHP_EOL."</Files>".PHP_EOL;fwrite($HTAccess_file, $htaccess_log);fclose($HTAccess_file);
            } if ($_SESSION['login_count'] >= 3 && $_SESSION['suspect_user'] == 'Suspect User Good') {
               // Login failed Under Possible User - Show Captcha
            $results['foo'] = "bar";
            require(ROOT.Admin_INCLUDES."/Forms/Captcha.php");
        } else { $_SESSION['login_count'] ++;}
        } else {   // User Not Logged In: Display Admin Login Form - Default Action On Start
    require(ROOT.Admin_INCLUDES."/Forms/Admin_Login.php");
     }
    }
```

Please help with adding count. I can't seem to post this the way it's asking me to.

My issue is here so I'm just editing the whole post & question. So where this-

```
    if ($_SESSION['login_count'] >= 3 && $_SESSION['suspect_user'] == 'Suspect User Good') {
               // Login failed Under Possible User - Show Captcha
            $results['foo'] = "bar";
            require(ROOT.Admin_INCLUDES."/Forms/Captcha.php");
   }
```

Nothing is happening. I think I'm getting caught in a loop. Any help on this will be amazing. Actually amazing in an understatement.

Comment: Woah, I feel like I'm playing word search

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm struggling how to display it in the editor.

Comment: You can use your IDE to format it and copy paste to the editor, after that you block the code and press the `{}` button

Answer (score 1):

use the session like this

```
function Admin_Login() {
  if (isset($_POST['Admin_Login'])) {
    if ($_POST['username'] == ADMIN_USERNAME && $_POST['password'] == ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = ADMIN_USERNAME;
      if (isset($_SESSION['suspect_user'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['suspect_user']);
        unset($_SESSION['login_count']);
      }
      header("Location: Admin.php");
    } elseif ($_POST['username'] != ADMIN_USERNAME && $_POST['password'] != ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
      $_SESSION['suspect_user'] = 'Suspected UserBad';
    } elseif ($_POST['username'] != ADMIN_USERNAME || $_POST['password'] != ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
      $_SESSION['suspect_user'] = 'Suspected User';
    }


    if ($_SESSION['login_count'] >= 5) {
      /* Too much login attempt, should blok the ip? */
    } else {
      $_SESSION['login_count'] ++;
    }
  }
}
```

the other is the same

Comment: I want something done after  5 attempts. A different session is given under suspect user like possible user. Something along those lines.

Comment: Whats wrong with your code is in the if ststement you make somting like `ADMIN_PASSWORD > 2` while you need another && to check other things

Comment: I have more than one elseif statement before the final else statement which is the default action. But it doesn't execute what I want for the <=5. Im not seeing why.

Comment: There are three sessions that can be executed. Admin, Possible Admin, & Suspect Admin. The Suspect admin is to be blocked from future attempts altogether. Where as Possible admin gets something else executed for an example a captcha. If that fails of course they will have to reset there password via email etc.

Comment: Your code sample only show when it's 5, I change a little if you want to make a message for it

Comment: May I give you it to post it correctly on the orginal post. I cant seem to get this to work for me on this site the way I want. It's frustrating me.

Comment: I edited the the original post but I think I'm going crossed eyes. LOL

Comment: But if the user attempts 5 times it always blocks them. I want the user to display the captcha if it is not bad user. @budirec

Comment: No need to block, you can do what ever you want. Displaying chapca, blocking ip, or anything